# Zend paginator - is it possible to set custom params?

Tags: php, zend-framework, pagination

I am taking care of a legacy Zend project. There is a table which is populated with some values using Paginator:

```
paginator = Zend_Paginator::factory( $this->_getRecords($filter1, $filter2)   );

$paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($this->_getParam('page'));
$this->view->paginator = $paginator;
```

Now here is the issue. This paginator does not know the filters ( filter1 and filter2 ).

Clicking on some page results in empty filter1 and filter2 values. What I want to do is to set those filters as params in the paginator, smthing like:

> /admin/users/index/page/7/filter1/value1/filter2/value2

Then to be able to say:

```
paginator = Zend_Paginator::factory( $this->_getRecords($this->_getParam('filter1'), $this->_getParam('filter2'))   );
```

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paginator doesn't generate urls. Urls are generated by router.

Transmit filters to template for current page

```
$this->view->paginator = $paginator;
$this->view->filters = array('filter1'=>$filter1, 'filter2'=>$filter2);
```

In template for current page transmit filters to paginator template

```
<?php echo $this->paginationControl($this->paginator, 'Sliding', 'pagination.tpl', array('filters'=>$this->filters)); ?>
```

In paginator template 'pagination.tpl' add them to url generation function

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url($this->filters + array('page'=>($this->current-1))); ?>">prev</a>

<a href="<?php echo $this->url($this->filters + array('page'=>($this->current+1))); ?>">next</a>
```